# Table of Contents - Font Parameters

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, titlesec, titletoc

The font, font size, and color for my section titles are different than the rest of my document. The goal for my table of contents is to use the same color (black) and font type (Fourier) as the rest of the document. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{adforn}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{Chivo}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{MSLightBlue}{rgb}{0.31,0.506,0.741}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\coolsec}[1] % custom section title
    {   
        \titleformat{\section}{\Large\flushright}{\textcolor{MSLightBlue}{\textsf{\thesection\enskip|}}}{1em}{}
        \section{\textcolor{MSLightBlue}{\textsf{#1}}}
    }

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\LARGE}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}

\addto\captionsamerican{% Replace "american" with the language you use
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}
    {\adforn{61}\quad Contents\quad\adforn{33}}}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}[0mm]{\large}{}{}{\dotfill\makebox[1em][l]{\thecontentspage}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\coolsec{FIRST}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\coolsec{SECOND}
\lipsum[2]
\newpage
\coolsec{THIRD}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for adding a minimal working example with your question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the formatting of the table of contents, you can use the `numberless` key, and the `explicit` option from `titlesec` (note all unnumbered sections – bibliography, &c., will be formatted similarly),  and  use `\titlecontents{\section}` in a consistent way. No tocloft required, only `titletoc`.

This yields a simpler code than what you had:

```
\documentclass[12pt, american]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{adforn}
\usepackage{Chivo}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{MSLightBlue}{rgb}{0.31,0.506,0.741}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
        \titleformat{\section}{\filleft\Large\color{MSLightBlue}\sffamily}{\thesection\enskip|}{1em}{#1}
        \titleformat{name=\section, numberless}[block]{\LARGE\filcenter}{}{0em}{\adforn{61}\quad#1\quad\adforn{33}}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}[0mm]{\large}{}{}{\enskip\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{FIRST}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\section{SECOND}
\lipsum[2]
\newpage
\section{THIRD}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution! I really appreciate everyone's help on this. I've been using LaTeX for only about a month, so I definitely have a lot more to learn. I come from an R coding background and LaTeX is proving to be even more challenging!